# Angular Radio button default active

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, checked

Why can't i get my radio button to be selected by default? What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioV" value="{'default': 'true', 'foo': 'false'}"/> One 
</label>

$scope.radioV = {
 'default'" : 'true'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

BASED on the concept of the example I provided try this,

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="radioV.default" value="{'default': 'true', 'foo': 'false'}"/> One 
</label>


$scope.radioV = {
 "default" : 'true'
}
```

Here is an example of what you want to achieve. You can understand it and fix your code yourself.

```
    <script>
  angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.color = {
        name: 'blue'
      };
      $scope.specialValue = {
        "id": "12345",
        "value": "green"
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red">
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue">
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="blue">
    Blue
  </label><br/>
  <tt>color = {{color.name | json}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
```

Here in this example, blue is selected by default. The $scope.color set it by default.

Took example from : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: sorry this doesnt help

Comment: Hey J. Doe thank you for the help, but unfortunately Im not having much luck. Do you reckon you could have a go here https://plnkr.co/edit/3bA6bK3KonabJzNuTCMn?p=preview Many thanks